# How can I avoid nested usage of `ng-repeat`?

Tags: angularjs

Sometimes I have to work with weird JSON objects from customers where 
I have to nest `ng-repeat` multiple times.

Is there a way to handle that in a single step? Perhaps something like `ng-repeat="item in items in evenMoreItems"`

**Example:**

```
<div ng-repeat="candle in candles">
    <div ng-repeat="object in candle ">
        {{ object.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's not possible :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use an underscore function to flatten your data so that its better suited. see: http://underscorejs.org/#flatten for an example..:

```
_.flatten([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
=> [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

With a bit of manipulation of the data you should be able to get a simple array for sg-repeat to use.

Comment: That's good for arrays I guess but not for JSON objects. Still +1 for thinking outside the box.